# Can we use 得 as "so... that"?

Tags: grammar

我的作业本丢了，急得 我 好像 热锅 上的 蚂蚁。
我今天累得不想吃饭。
Is 得 used here like the "so... that" structure? Or are we supposed to use 的 for the first sentence? How can we translate these sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function of "得“ in these two sentences is to indicate a [degree complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/degree_complement). The general structure for this kind of degree complement used with an adjective is

> adjective + 得 + X

where X is some phrase. There are many different structures for X. When X contains a predicate, we can often translate it as "so [adj] that [clause]."

> 我今天累得不想吃饭。
> I'm so tired that I don't want to eat.

When X is a comparison, the degree complement can often be translated to "as [adj] as [noun phrase]." These comparisons are frequently idiomatic.

> 我的作业本丢了，急得我好像热锅上的蚂蚁。
> I lost my workbook, making me as anxious as a cat on a hot tin roof. 
> (literal translation: as anxious as an ant on a hot pan)

Here are some other common degree complements involving comparison.

> 他饿得跟什么似的。
> He's as hungry as anything. 
> (literal translation: as hungry as something)

> 我累得跟狗一样。
> I'm dog-tired. 
> (literal translation: as tired as a dog)

[Here's a post](https://international-chinese.com/%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%A6%E8%A1%A5%E8%AF%AD/) (in Chinese) that gives other examples of short, idiomatic degree complements.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a "so ... that" structure.

急 tells us you are anxious or worried. The phrase 我好像热锅上的蚂蚁 tells us how anxious or worried you are. If I was an ant in that situation, I'd be worried! Saying, "Stay cool bro!" won't help!

So I suppose you could say:

> (I am) anxious (so that) I resemble an ant on a hotplate.

Six hot little feet! (I don't know about ants, but I read butterflies taste things with their feet!)

我的作业本丢了。
I lost my homework book.

> 热锅上的蚂蚁：形容心理烦躁、焦急， 坐立不安的样子。
> ant on a hotplate: describes the appearance  of being agitated, anxious, jittery.

急得我好像热锅上的蚂蚁。
(I) am as anxious as an ant on a hotplate.

我今天累得不想吃饭。
I am tired today, I don't want to eat.

You could express the above so:

今天我太累了，连饭都不想吃。
Today I am so tired, I don't even want to eat!

Answer (score 1):

的 is used to mark possession, or make an adjective/possessive phrase to describe the noun/object that follows.

- **我的**作业本丢了 - I lost **my** notepad.
- **热锅上的**蚂蚁 - Ants **on the hot pot**.

得 has quite a few uses, but here, it indicates "the state/degree/extent" of the action word (累) proceeds it.

- 我今天**累得**不想吃饭 - I am **too tired** to eat today.

Here is an excellent reference material - https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/de-grammar-summary/